# convert database time field to formatted string

Tags: delphi

How can I format the result of 'INT_TIME' so it does not display like Time.
'Mytime' is time field and 'INT_TIME' is string.

```
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
 ADOTable1.Fields.FieldByName('INT_TIME').asString := TimeToStr(ADOTable1.FieldByName('MYTIME').AsDateTime) ;
end;
```

Now,the string displays just like the time field (07:30:00).
New to this ...

EDITED :

Comment: `7,30` is not an integer. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have no problem with string too but I cant figure out how to format the output result.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: No, it does not. `7,30` is not an integer, because integers don't have decimal separators regardless of locale. Integers are whole numbers.

Comment: Define that field as date time, calculate with date time. Just for the final formatting (in your case conversion from date time to string) implement the `OnGetText` event for that field.

Comment: @user3351050, do you realize what `07:30:00` is `7.5` hrs, not `7.3`?

Comment: @Lama - what do I write ?

Comment: @user3351050, you forgot `T` prefix. I'm a `T`ype of `Lama` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need your `INT_TIME` field. (`INT_TIME` is a terrible name for a string column, by the way.) You can use `AsDateTime` of the `TField` itself, and use the functions from `DateUtils` to retrieve the separate hour and minute values. As @TLama says in his comment, you can use the OnGetText event if you're only using the value for display, instead of using a calculated field:

```
procedure TForm4.ClientDataSet1MyTimeGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
  DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
  Text := Format('%d%s%d', [HourOf(Sender.AsDateTime),
                            FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator,
                            MinuteOf(Sender.AsDateTime)]);
end;
```